# PyMuPDF | inserted image is in the wrong place of a pdf page

Tags: python, image, pdf, pymupdf

I need to insert an image into some pages of a pdf and I use [insertImage](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page/#Page.insertImage). Following the example I provide `fitz.Rect(0, 0, 50, 50)` as I want to place the image in the top left corner of the page. Works perfectly for all pdfs, but one - a scanned document for which the image appears somewhere in the center of the page and the image is also 90 rotated. What might cause the difference in the result for that particular pdf and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [PyMuPDF documentation here](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/#misplaced-item-insertions-on-pdf-pages), due to inconsistencies in how the PDF was created, it is possible the origin of that particular document is not the standard global origin on top-left.

The following snippet resets the geometry of the page:

```py
if not(page._isWrapped):
    page._wrapContents()
```

If this workaround doesn't work the best, there are other potential solutions listed on the site.

Comment: Thanks! Do you by any chance know how to fix the geometry regarding a ```fitz.Point``` which is needed for ```insertText```, text I am trying to place is in the wrong place again and none of the listed solutions work

Comment: I don't get your question there. Do you mean to say you're facing issues when plotting a point, but a rectangle is drawn at the correct location? Geometry is related to the document, and not the type of object you are trying to render.

Comment: Exactly, same point is rendered at different locations in different pdfs (one considers top left corner as the beginning while the other - bottom left). insertText uses Points to indicate first line of the text, hence my text appears in different places depending on the pdf

Comment: Sorry, the closest that I can find that is related is [this](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/367)

Answer (score 1):

I test with Python 3.7.3;  PyMuPDF 1.20.2
no need to check page._isWrapped,   ( actuall it will show:
AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute '_isWrapped'
)

only the below lines is enough:

```py
import fitz

def test_func():
    doc = fitz.open('test.pdf')
    for page in doc:
        page.wrap_contents()
        # do some other stuff
    doc.save('test-new.pdf')
```